# How to send the BreezeSession's value with each of requests to Adobe Connect's Web Service?

Tags: c#, api, postman, adobe-connect

I have read the Adobe Connect's document, I could not understand that where should I place my BreezeSession's value (especially in Postman) when I want to call other actions which need authentication and BreezSession's value to work.

Step 1: User can login with his username and password with this GET action:

```
$"{AdobeConnectServerURL}/api/xml?action=login" +
            $"&login={login.Username}" +
            $"&password={login.Password}";
```

The code, results BreezeSession's value in its header. So my authentication and login works perfectly.

Now imagine I want to call another Adobe Connect's action which creates a new meeting, I have to create the meeting with an authorized user's BreezeSession.

How can I send the BreezeSession's value among create-user's action to Adobe Connect Server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer I hope that it will be helpful for others.

Inside the URL you can use the segment named session:

YourURLHere/api/xml?session=`YourBreezeSession`&action=YourActionHere

or you can set cookie using this function inside your code for calling APIs.

```
public async Task<string> CallApi(string apiUrl)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiUrl);
        var cc = new CookieContainer();
        cc.Add(new Cookie("BREEZESESSION", "Your BreezeSession Value Here", "/", "your URL"));
        request.CookieContainer = cc;
        var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        var x = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        return x;

    }
```